# Reading the information From Column

Tags: vb.net

I linked a Database to my VB.net form and i want to read a specific column's information but can't find any answers. The DataGrid contains information on people. I want to read the very last column the name is "Call" and i want to store those values into a list so i can loop them through a specific function.

```
For Each line As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
                If Not line.IsNewColumn Then
                    MessageBox.Show(line.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "," & line.Cells(1).Value.ToString)
                End If
            Next
```

I found this and it kinda looks like what I'm trying to do but I don't know how to alter it or put it into a list so any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
    Dim colIndex As Integer
    colIndex = 0
    Dim strList As New List(Of String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        strList.Add(DataGridView1.Item(colIndex, i).Value.ToString)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(strList(i))
    Next
```

Listbox1 is just a test tool in order for me to see if it works, and it did :)
strList is the list that you want, and colIndex is the index of column "Call" in the DGV

Another approach is this, thanks to Plutonix for pointing out some important details.

```
    Dim strList As New List(Of String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        strList.Add(DataGridView1.Item("Call", i).Value.ToString)
    Next
    MsgBox(strList.count) 'number of items in the list.
```

Comment: colIndex could be `Columns.Count-1`, no?  or even == `Columns("Call").Index` But  `colIndex = the very last column` probably wont work

Comment: What part of that is the actual item? strlist? and do i need to declare ListBox1 or get rid of it? cause its giving me a warning lol

Comment: read: `Listbox1 is just a test tool` use your List in its place

Comment: @plutonix yes, it could be, but what I was trying to say here is the 'index' of column "Call" from where he will get the data.

Comment: @landers yes you can get rid of listbox1.

Comment: @Landers_15, you almost certainly will need more info than just "Call" since it will have no context - no Caller or Callee associated with it.  Using Codemunkeee's loop you should be able to see how process the DGV in a loop and simple use that elsewhere with all the associated details.

Comment: I am going to post all my code here cause its not working at least not in the capacity im trying to make it work Its my fault entirely i can only see this problem from 1 side

Answer (score 1):

My whole Code is as follows I am trying to take the data from the column named "call" for each person to send them an email to their cell phone. there is also text box's so you can send to 1 person rather then the whole list.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ContactsDataSet.VBQuery' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.VBQueryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ContactsDataSet.VBQuery)
    ' Set the caption bar text of the form.   
    Me.Text = "Texting From Email"
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try

        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim self As New MailAddress("xxx1@gmail.com")
        Dim strCarriers As New List(Of String)
        Dim colIndex As Integer
        Dim strList As New List(Of String)

        colIndex = 0
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("yyy@gmail.com", "blank")
        Smtp_Server.Port = 587
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

        strCarriers.Add("@pm.sprint.com")
        strCarriers.Add("@vtext.com")
        strCarriers.Add("@tmomail.net")
        strCarriers.Add("@txt.att.net")

        If rad1.Checked = True Then

            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                strList.Add(DataGridView1.Item(colIndex, i).Value.ToString)
                'strList.Items.Add(strList(i))
                'strList.Add(DataGridView1.Item("Call", i).Value.ToString)

                For Each line In strList

                    For Each Carrier As String In strCarriers

                        e_mail = New MailMessage()
                        e_mail.From = self
                        e_mail.To.Add("strlist" + "Carrier")
                        e_mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
                        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
                        e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
                        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)

                    Next Carrier
                Next
            Next
        ElseIf rad1.Checked = False Then

            For Each Carrier As String In strCarriers

                e_mail = New MailMessage()
                e_mail.From = self
                e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text + Carrier)
                e_mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
                e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
                e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
                Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)

            Next
        End If

        MsgBox("Mail Sent")

    Catch error_t As Exception
        MsgBox(error_t.ToString)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: you didnt set colIndex...and you have a weird nested loop

Comment: have you tried changing `e_mail.To.Add("strlist" + "Carrier")` to `e_mail.To.Add(line + Carrier)` ???

Comment: Yeah I am trying to Send 4 emails essentially to each Item in Call and colIndex is set right above Smtp_Server unless im doing it wrong

Comment: colindex=0 is the first column, not the last, what goes in that column?  Is "Call" the NAME of the column or the text that goes in it?

Comment: there's something wrong with your loop.. you should get the list first before using it..

Comment: he is going to iterate strList however many times there are rows in the DGV  == "weird nested loop".  dont really need a list - DGV makes a swell list.

Comment: @asker you should post another question for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 colIndex = number of the column... Columns.Count - 1 should work if it
 ' really is the last column

 Dim NumToCall As String

 For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
     ' dont need
     'strList.Add(DataGridView1.Item(colIndex, i).Value.ToString)

     NumToCall = DataGridView1.Item(colIndex, i).Value.ToString 
     ' you cal also reference by name:
     NumToCall = DataGridView1.Item("Call", i).Value.ToString


     ' Send Email
     e_mail.To.Add(NumToCall  & Carrier)

 Next
```

This is a problem too:

```
 For Each Carrier As String In strCarriers
```

Given a recipient of "Ziggy", it will try to send to Ziggy@pm.sprint.com, Ziggy@vtext.com, Ziggy@tmomail.net and Ziggy@txt.att.net.  You need to associate the carrier with each person to avoid that (if the carrier or email address is not part of the grid to start with).  Otherwise, break it into Functions to `GetCarrier`, `SendMail` etc, not loops in loops in loops.

...and you should not eat all the exceptions like that

Comment: Well the point was to send to 4 different carriers each to cover all the bases eventually i will just drop that but im getting a null exception raised with 
 If DataGridView1.Item(colIndex, i).Value.ToString = "Call" Then

Comment: from above: is the NAME of the last column CALL or are you looking for text like "Call" in some column???

Comment: I am trying to get the Items in Column "Call" into a list that i can loop through and send a message and now im feeling like an idiot with all this help and its still not working sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: If the DGB is bound to a query then that means there is a DB column named "Call", right?  Ok, so WHAT is in that column?

Comment: That column contains a phone number but its a query that combines 2 other columns names Area Code and Number pretty self explanatory and yeah the Column name is Call

Comment: see Edit  - if the CALL column is a recipient ID, then it combines looping on the DGV with your code to send to 'Column(Call).Value & @whatever.com'

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your first if statement.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    strList.Add(DataGridView1.Item("Call", i).Value.ToString)
Next
For Each str In strList
       For Each Carrier In strCarriers
           e_mail = New MailMessage()
           e_mail.From = self
           e_mail.To.Add(str + Carrier)
           e_mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
           e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
           e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
           Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
       Next
   Next
```

Comment: Line 43 = strList.Add(DataGridView1.Item(colIndex, i).Value.ToString)

Comment: throws a null exception and idk how to handle it

Comment: use `DataGridView1.Item("Call", i).Value.ToString` WE dont know how many columns there are or what you are using for the index

Comment: @Landers_15, if you hold the mouse over variables and objects, VS will tell you what they are/their value and the thing that is Nothing is the cause of the exception

Comment: in addition to @Plutonix's comment, you should also learn to use Debug and breakpoints, it's tools like that are very powerful ya know. :)